# Windows 8 require repair after install Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, windows-8, bootloader, boot-repair

I just installed Ubuntu along with my Windows 8.1.

After installing Ubuntu and changed to boot priority to 1.Ubuntu 2.Window Boot, my Windows crash (Pic Provided).

Whenever I choose the windows from GRUB(Pic Provided), it says something is missing and require repair.

How can I solve it?

[image: The screen i got after select windows from GRUB (Windows Boot Manager)]

[image: my GRUB]

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows. Or if Windows is hibernated/fast start up on or needs chkdsk then grub will not boot Windows. You may be able to directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu, often f10 or f12 from UEFI, but before grub starts to load. http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation You seem to have a lot of duplicate entries in grub. What repairs did you do?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you did not disable Secure boot in your BIOS.  First boot into your BIOS, under any boot tab, find Secure boot, and disable it.

If this does not work,  you will need to get your windows repair CD, boot into the Recovery console, and then run

*bootrec /fixmbr*

*bootrec /fixboot*

This should disable your GRUB bootloader, but do not be alarmed.  Boot into Windows, open and administrative command prompt, and type the following:

*bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi*

Reboot, and you should have GRUB, and it should boot back into Windows.

Comment: Secure Boot *should not* cause this type of problem. (That said, many EFIs and boot programs are buggy, so I wouldn't entirely rule it out as a possibility -- but it's *very* far down the list of suspects.) AFAIK, the Windows `bootrec /fixmbr` command fixes BIOS-mode boot problems and so is pointless at best on this EFI-based computer. The rest of this answer might help overcome the immediate problem, but chances are oldfred is correct that the problem is caused by a failure to disable Fast Startup and Hibernate. Those features *must* be disabled to safely dual-boot with Windows 8 or later.

Comment: Thanks, going to try it now. Just so you know, I am still able to boot into Windows if i change the first boot priority to windows. But the bad side of this is I can't go to the grub and access Ubuntu.